# How to hide empty ratings using Rate module?

Tags: rating

I run a site that uses the Rate module on Drupal 7, using the 5 star rating.  A lot of the items haven't got any ratings yet, so are displayed as 5 blank stars, which makes it look like they've got a score of 0 out of 5.  Is there a way of only displaying a score if there is at least one rating?

Answer (score 0):

How would people rate the item the very first time if the widget is hidden?

Look in Rate module's template folder for rate-template-fivestar.tpl.php. Copy it over into your theme's template folder then make changes.

I think the variable $count might be available (Number of votes), so you could print out a message if $count is 0 to say that the item has not yet been rated.